# How to make advertising script be the latest element loaded?

Tags: javascript

I want to make ads to load last.so,after all the website's page elements are loaded,what code do i need to make an ad load last ?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've replaced the CSS tag with JavaScript. I've assumed it was a typo, feel free to clarify if it wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can  put the advertisement code inside `window.onload` event so that it executes after the page is loaded. Another method is to put the advertisements code at the bottom of the page because browsers read the document from top to bottom. If the advertisements are loaded via javascript you could use script injection like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer>

function loadAds(src) {
    //write script
    document.write('<script src="' + src + '" type="text/javascript"></script>');
}
//function call
loadAds('http://example.com/advertisements.js');

</script>
```

"The defer attribute gives a hint to the browser that the script does not create any content so the browser can optionally defer interpreting the script"- http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/ ; 
Another article if you use Google Adsense would be: http://adsense.blogspot.com/2011/03/making-web-faster-for-all-adsense-for.html

Comment: thank your for the response. this is the code type   <!-- BEGIN STANDARD TAG - 300 x 250 - ROS: Run-of-site - DO NOT MODIFY -->
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="http://adserving.ad.com/st?ad_type=ad&amp;ad_size=300x250&amp;section=165"></SCRIPT>
<!-- END TAG -->